# Stuck on trying to even start proving $2\mid (n^4-3)$ if and only if $4\mid (n^2 + 3)$

Tags: induction

How would you prove  $2\mid (n^4-3)\iff 4\mid (n^2 + 3)$.  Can you use induction on both at same time?  Can I just do it directly somehow?

Comment: Hint: consider the parity of $n$

Comment: Hint: $\;n^4-3\,$ is even iff $n$ is odd, in which case $\,n=2k+1\,$ for some $k\,$, and $(2k+1)^2+3=\cdots$

Answer (score 2):

$4 \mid (n^2+3) \implies n$ is odd $\implies n^4$ is odd $\implies n^4 -3$ is even $\implies 2 \mid (n^4 - 3)$.

$2 \mid (n^4 - 3) \implies n$ is odd $\implies n = 2k + 1$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z} \implies n^2 = 4k^2 + 4k + 1 \implies n^2 + 3 = 4k^2 + 4k +4 \implies 4 \mid (n^2 + 3)$.

Comment: Just as a tip, you can use "\mid" instead of "|" to show 'divides'. e.g. $2\mid 4$ as opposed to $2|4$.

Comment: This was very useful....I used it in a very round about way with the fact n must be odd both ways since iff statement...Thank You.

Comment: @Dave: Thanks for the tip.. It will be useful to me in the future. :-)

Answer (score 0):

$$2\mid n^4-3 \iff 2\mid(n^2+1)(n+1)(n-1)-2$$

$$\iff 2\mid n+1 \text{ and } 2\mid n-1 \iff 4\mid n^2-1 \iff 4\mid n^2+3.$$

Answer (score 0):

$2 \mid (n^4 - 3)$ iff $2\cdot 2 \mid 2\cdot(n^4 - 3)$.  So it is equivalent to proving

$$2n^4 - 6 \equiv 0 \text{ iff } n^2 + 3 \equiv 0 \pmod 4$$

And there are only 4 cases you need to check ($0 \le n < 4$).